# coreFoundationUnknownErr when creating an application with osacompile from an applescript

Tags: macos, applescript

I have the following applescript `Spyder3.applescript` :

```
on run
 do shell script "/usr/local/miniconda3/bin/spyder3"
end run
```

I want to compile it to an Application, so I type this command :

`$ sudo osacompile -o /Application/Spyder3.app Spyder3.applescript`

but I get this an `coreFoundationUnknownErr` error :

`osacompile: couldn't write to file /Application/Spyder3.app: coreFoundationUnknownErr (-4960).`

Can you help me ?

Comment: If you're trying to appify a command line executable, then have a look at: [Platypus](https://sveinbjorn.org/platypus)

Comment: @user3439894 Thank your answer, however, I'd like to be able to do that from the command line without having to install an graphical application

Comment: I do not have `miniconda3` or `spyder3` installed, so I can't test with that, however I have no problem from Terminal, creating a `testapp.applescript` file, e.g. `touch testapp.applescript`, ... `nano testapp.applescript`, ... adding three lines, `on run`, `say "hello"` and `end run`, saving it... `Control+X` `Y` `Enter` and then `osacompile -o /Applications/testapp.app testapp.applescript`, without `sudo` under macOS 10.12.5. It does so without error and I can go to Applications in Finder and double-click the _testapp_ app, and it runs without issue. **Can you do that without error?**

Comment: @user3439894 You are right, I don't need the `sudo`

Answer (score 1):

I was mistaken about the Applications directory name.

I wrote `/Application/Spyder3.app` instead of `/Applications/Spyder3.app`

I'm sorry